# Installing Jenkins using jenkins operator in a separate namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-operator

I am following the below document to install  `jenkins-oprator` using `helm` under `jenkins` namespace . I am using the following values

```
       jenkins.enabled: true
       namespace: jenkins
       replicaCount: 3
       image: virtuslab/jenkins-operator:v0.7.0 
       webhook.enabled: true
```

Installation is successful as can be shown below

```
  $ helm list -n jenkins

NAME    NAMESPACE  REVISION  UPDATED  STATUS   CHART     APP VERSION
jenkins jenkins   2023-09-17 14:28:16.815839332 +0000 UTC deployed jenkins-operator-0.8.0  0.8.0
```

But it is listing one of the components inside the `default` namespace

```
       jenkins-jenkins         2/2     Running                  0          10m
```

Can somebody please guide why it is installing one of the components in `default` namespace when I specified to be installed in `jenkins` namespace.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/kubernetes-operator/docs/getting-started/latest/installing-the-operator/

Answer (score 2):

Good day!
I've just tried to create values.yaml as YAML format:

```
jenkins:
  enabled: true
  namespace: jenkins
```

After `helm install jenkins jenkins/jenkins-operator -n jenkins -f values.yaml` i have no any resources in default ns.

An example of filling values.yaml can be found [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jenkins/jenkins-operator?modal=values).

I hope this helps.